# Why does my way of reading number of lines in a text file not work?k C

Tags: c

So i'm trying to write a function that will read number of lines in a text file. However, I notice that the function will not exit even when it exceeded number of lines in my text file. Why? Why does it work when i put

```
fgets(sentence, 70, inputFile);
```

before counter ++

```
int GetNumLine(char *fileName){

    FILE *inputFile;

    //counter are used to store number of lines
    int counter = 0;

    char sentence [70];

    inputFile = fopen(fileName,"r");

    //if there are anything wrong with inputfile
    if(inputFile == NULL){
        printf("Error while opening file");
        exit(1);
    }


    while(!feof(inputFile) ){


        counter++;
    }

    fclose(inputFile);

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: You're not doing anything to the file pointer in the while loop. `fgets()` reads a line and advances the pointer.

Comment: Because you never read anything from the file, you stay at the beginning!

Answer (score 1):

This will be always true

```
while(!feof(inputFile))
```

you need to read from the file in order to reach the end and the `EOF` marker be set, i'd recommend doing it this way

```
int chr;
while ((chr = fgetc(inputFile)) != EOF)
    counter += (chr == '\n') ? 1 : 0;
```

when you put `fgets()` before `counter++` you read from the file and change the position in the `FILE *` structure, when you try to read beyond the end of the file, `EOF` will be set and `feof(inputFile)` will return non-zero.

The code with the `fgets()` works but is not robust because you can have a line with more than `69` characters and it will be counted twice, with my suggestion the result will be always correct.